# Add a user control to a panel on the main form in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a user control that I have added to a panel on a form.
I have code that will place additional copies of this on the form need to know how to add these to the panel instead. Panel does not have a controls property.

```
   If intCount > 0 Then
        For intindex = 0 To intCount - 1
            If intindex > 0 Then
                Load CICMod(intindex)
                With CICMod(intindex)
                    .Width = 8775
                    .Height = 3735
                    .Top = CICMod(intindex - 1).Top + 3735
                    .Left = 360
                    .Visible = True
                End With
            End If
            With CICMod(intindex)
                .RecordID = rs.Fields(0)
                .Revision = rs.Fields(1)
                .Seq = rs.Fields(2)
                .Who = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(3)), "", rs.Fields(3))
                .Entrydate = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(4)), "01/01/1900", rs.Fields(4))
                .Hours = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(5)), 0, rs.Fields(5))
                .Project = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(6)), "", rs.Fields(6))
                .Types = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(7)), "", rs.Fields(7))
                .Names = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(8)), "", rs.Fields(8))
                .Description = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(9)), "", rs.Fields(9))
            End With
            If Not rs.EOF Then
                rs.MoveNext
            End If
        Next
        rs.Close
    Else

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
Set CICMod(intindex).Container = Frame1
```

The `container` property sets the parent of that control, in this case the "panel", which doesn't exist in VB6 by the way, to Frame1 so `CICMod(intindex)` is now contained by Frame1.

Alternatively, you can use the optional Container parameter of the .Add method.

```
object.Add (ProgID, name, container)
```

which would be used like

```
Set ctlDynamic = Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl", "myctl", Frame1)
```

However, many have found that method to not always work as desired so I would recommend the first. Here's some more reading if wish to try the latter (both samples above were derived from these). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277578(v=vs.60).aspx or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190670

Comment: Add more explanation and details on why this might work and how it applies to user's project

Comment: @dbmitch I thought the answer was pretty obvious and self explanatory.